# The best practice for writing of examples

Tags: documentation

I have written some projects. I try to annotate or comment all possible (hard to say if correctly toward clean explaining).

I would like to write documentation for it, but I have problem with examples.

It is not problem to write in annotation above each function (where it is really needed) examples of all possible using of that function - but it would be good to describe each of those examples.

And for this, it would be better to use additional file where it will be written as well as possible. But what *format* and what filetype to use for it?

Secondary question is (partly related to main one), that I am not sure if is it needed to examples would be *running*. Because in case of functions stored in traits it is probably very hard to make those examples *running*.

Comment: Questions asking for best practices tend to be very broad, and get very opinion-based answers. See [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353) and [How to ask a “best practice” question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7091). E.g. there could be two contradictory answers “examples should be executable so that they can be copied” and “examples need not be executable because they are illustration”. This is why I've written about *my* opinions at [some other place](http://lukasatkinson.de/2015/api-documentation/#example-tips).

Comment: The best examples get executed on each CI build. =)

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking - use Markdown format.

Most document generators can read markdown files to include in their documentation output. [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html), for example, can include markdown text inline or from external files.

Whether examples should be complete or not is up to you. Some complex examples show just the necessary code so the extraneous parts do not get in the way of the example. Personally, I would make a distinction between code examples of use, and demos of the program. compilable, runnable programs should be included separately so the user can see them work. These are not really part of documentation unless you take sections and paste them as examples.

Answer (score 2):

Code examples should *illustrate usage.*

For example, here is a comment I wrote for a business rules engine in C#:

```
/// <summary>
/// Creates LINQ expressions that represent validation rules, and compound
/// expressions representing rule sets via the use of the And and Or methods below.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This class is a re-implementation of Joseph Albahari's Predicate Builder class
/// with two type parameters instead of one and some additional utility methods
/// and logging. See http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx
/// </remarks>
/// <example>
/// Suggested usage:
/// <code>
/// <![CDATA[
///      var licenseNumberMustMatch = Rule.Create<CacheRecord, AnswerLicense>((ed, al) => string.Equals(ed.RegistrationNumber, al.LicenseNumber, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
///      var legalEntityNameMustMatch = Rule.Create<CacheRecord, LegalEntity>((ed, le) => ed.LicenceeName.EntityMatches(le.LegalEntityname));
///      var ruleSet = LicenseNumberMustMatch.And(LegalEntityNameMustMatch); // Type inference works here; no need to specify type parameters.
/// 
///      Rule.Execute(ruleset, cacheRecord, answerLicense, logger, "US_DOC Verify");
/// ]]>
/// </code>
/// </example>
```

By providing a complete example, the software developer no longer has to guess at what an ideal implementation looks like.  In fact, (s)he can copy/paste the example, change the names and parameters, add some additional conditions, and be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely prefer executable example code over a documentation. The reason is simple. As your code base evolves you might easily "forget" to update your documentation. This might not happen with your executable code as your refactoring tools in your IDE might automatically update the example code. And you might also add tests for your examples codes that are executed in your CI system.

Comment: However to go searching inside examples for 3 lines of code, when you have documentation, is tedious. Better to have focused documentation and comprehensive examples (if possible). Of course IF you have to pick one, well, examples are better.